# Change the resolution of Windows 10 in Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution

I am using Windows 10 and I accidentally changed the resolution to 1024x768. After that the screen size reduced and after some time the screen is not visible. Now I can't see my screen. When I login to safe mode the screen is showing, but there is no option to change the resolution (it automatically takes the high resolution). How can I make my screen visible. I tried connecting an external screen, but in safe mode when I press windows+P it shows "Your PC can't project to another screen try reinstalling the driver". Please help.

P.S. Now I am able to see the screen on my external monitor. I have reverted the screen resolution to 1920x1080. But the laptop monitor is not showing anything. It only shows the laptop brand name at the booting time.

Comment: What exactly did you do accidentally?

Comment: @harrymc       I wanted to take the screenshots at low resolution, so I changed the resolution. Now I am able to see the screen on my external monitor. But the laptop monitor is not showing anything. It only shows the laptop brand name at the booting time.

Comment: @Akhilesh If you right-click on the desktop (on any monitor that works), then go to "Display settings", does the laptop monitor show up? If yes, what does it say under "Multiple displays"?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The issue was the brightness was reduced. Laptop's F11 key has brightness decrease function too. So while making the application full screen I accidentally reduced the brightness :)